# LINK2019 when using PCAP++

Tags: c++, pcap, pcapplusplus

I am trying to use the pcap++ library. I have downloaded the libraries for the VS2017, I linked the libraries and also the header files.

The libraries are:

```
Common++.lib
Packet++.lib
Pcap++.lib
```

and I made sure I am using the right release library.

When I build the solution, I am getting the error: LNK2019  unresolved external symbol _pcap_setfilter referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall pcpp::IPcapDevice::setFilter

The code is simple:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "IPv4Layer.h"
#include "Packet.h"
#include "PcapFileDevice.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // open a pcap file for reading
    pcpp::PcapFileReaderDevice reader("1_packet.pcap");
    if (!reader.open())
    {
        printf("Error opening the pcap file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    reader.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: I imagine you need to link to the pcap library

Comment: @AlanBirtles I did that already. Unfortunately It did not work

Comment: I'm not sure if you downloaded the library files from the release page: https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/releases/download/v21.11/pcapplusplus-21.11-windows-vs2017.zip, if you do you will find a `README.release` file inside with detailed instructions on how to build your code and also an example VS project/solution you can use

Comment: @AhmedYousif you are linking to the pcap++ library, but not to the underlying pcap library that it wraps. You need to link to both

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by add:

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: By the default, compiler warning will notice you the missing symbol of the function. Then you can google it and locate which header/library it in. And manully load the static lib or dll for it.

Answer (score 0):

I added included path and libs to Qt .pro file. Pcap++ doesn't work alone. You can read Readme.txt file for more information. It needs dependencies those are Npcap or WinPcap. You should need to download SDK of those and include.

- Make sure you have WinPcap or Npcap Developer's pack installed (WinPcap Dev Pack can be downloaded from [winpcap](https://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm), Npcap SDK can be downloaded from [npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/#download))

I created external directory for external libraries. And I included libs to Qt .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
    $$PWD/external/pcapplusplus/include/pcapplusplus \
    $$PWD/external/pcapplusplus/include \
    $$PWD/external/WpdPack/Include \
    $$PWD/external/WpdPack/Include/pcap \
    $$PWD/external/npcap/Include \
    $$PWD/external/npcap/Include/pcap \

LIBS += \
    -L$$PWD/external/pcapplusplus/lib -lPcap++ -lCommon++ -lPacket++ \
    -L$$PWD/external/WpdPack/Lib/x64 -lPacket -lwpcap \
    -L$$PWD/external/npcap/Lib/x64 -lPacket -lwpcap \

DEPENDPATH += \
    $$PWD/external/pcapplusplus/include/pcapplusplus \
    $$PWD/external/pcapplusplus/include \
    $$PWD/external/WpdPack/Include \
    $$PWD/external/WpdPack/Include/pcap \
    $$PWD/external/npcap/Include \
    $$PWD/external/npcap/Include/pcap \
```